# Crontab Python cannot write log file and execute

Tags: python, cron

Yesterday, I was able to write log file and execute Crontab in Mac.
However, today I cannot write log file and execute Crontab at all.

What I did yesterday was :

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
```

To try to handle Chrome.

After it, I can execute Python file in VS code but cannot do anything in Crontab.

Experts, could you help me?

My code for crontab is :

```
* * * * * /Users/XXXXXX/anaconda3/bin/python &&  /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/python/.vscode/python/1234.py >> Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/python/test_log.log 2>&1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To check crontab logs for errors that might show what is going on try

```
grep -i cron /var/log/syslog
```

If crontab was executed but there was an error in the script, that might be sent to system email if it is setup, else you might check

```
/var/spool/mail
```

for cron error messages.